# Which site is showing in the WebView on an app

Tags: android, android-webview

So I have this app and I am convinced they use a WebView to show a website. But, how can I find which page (URL) they are showing inside the app?

Comment: If you have access to the APK file, decompile it.

Comment: Don't have the apk file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.

You might be lucky with watching logcat, if they print out some info for the sake of debugging.

Comment: Where can I find the logcat? Emulate it in eclipse?

Comment: Didn't find the url in logcat.